# How to wrap a @KafkaListener which is handled by seekToCurrentErrorHandler with a latch for testing

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, spring-kafka-test

I have a kafka listener which throws an exception and goes to seektocurrenterrorhandler for handling. I am trying to wrap the listener to add a latch and assert on it for my testing. But it seems to be not working. Can someone please suggest.

Listener:

```
@KafkaListener(id="testRetry",topics = "sr1", groupId = "retry-grp", containerFactory = "kafkaRetryListenerContainerFactory")
    public void listen1(ConsumerRecord<String, Anky> record,
            @Header(KafkaHeaders.DELIVERY_ATTEMPT) int delivery, Acknowledgment ack) throws UserException {
            throw new UserException(code.getDbError());

    }
```

Config:

```
@Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Anky> kafkaRetryListenerContainerFactory(SeekToCurrentErrorHandler seekToCurrentErrorHandler) {

        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Anky> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
        factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(AckMode.MANUAL_IMMEDIATE);
        // to get the no retry count from the header
        factory.getContainerProperties().setDeliveryAttemptHeader(true);
        factory.setErrorHandler(seekToCurrentErrorHandler);
        // to keep the consumers alive the failure gets reported to broker so that
        // consumers remain alive
        factory.setStatefulRetry(true);
        factory.setConcurrency(2);
        return factory;
    }


    @Bean
    public SeekToCurrentErrorHandler seekToCurrentErrorHandler(DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer deadLetterPublishingRecoverer) {
        SeekToCurrentErrorHandler errorHandler = new SeekToCurrentErrorHandler((record, exception) -> {
            //do nothing
        });
        errorHandler.setCommitRecovered(true);
        errorHandler.setBackOffFunction((record, exception) -> {
            return new FixedBackOff(0L,5L);

        });
        return errorHandler;
    }
```

Test:

```
@Test
public void testRetry() throws Exception,UserException {
    Anky msg = new Anky();
    this.template.send("sr1", "1234", msg);
    CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
            ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<?, ?> container = (ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<?, ?>) kafkaListenerEndpointRegistry
            .getListenerContainer("testRetry");
    container.stop();
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    AcknowledgingConsumerAwareMessageListener<String, Anky> messageListener = (AcknowledgingConsumerAwareMessageListener<String, Anky>) container
            .getContainerProperties().getMessageListener();

    container.getContainerProperties()
            .setMessageListener(new AcknowledgingConsumerAwareMessageListener<String, Anky() {

                @Override
                public void onMessage(ConsumerRecord<String, Anky> data, Acknowledgment acknowledgment,
                        Consumer<?, ?> consumer) {
                    messageListener.onMessage(data, acknowledgment, consumer);
                    latch.countDown();
                }

            });
    container.start();
    assertThat(latch.await(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)).isTrue();
    
}
```

Comment: How the latch can work there if you throw an exception from your listener? The `countDown()` is just not reachable...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `try...finally` block.

```java
try {
    messageListener.onMessage(data, acknowledgment, consumer);
}
finally {
    latch.countDown();
}
```

Comment: i am also doing a verify on a service method injected to the listener to make sure the retries are tried 5 times and if i do a latch.countdown() in finally then it only retries once not 5times...

Comment: That doesn't make sense - did you increase the `CountDownLatch` to 5?

Comment: Hi Gary, i am seeing that sometimes the test doesnot invoke the consumer and fails randomly with the latch returning false on the jenkins build.. why would that be happening? can you please suggest...

Comment: It's probably a race condition, most likely caused by not setting `ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG` to `earliest`. It defaults to `latest` which means the consumer will not see the record if it starts after the template has sent it.

Comment: I checked, consumer config is set to earliest... but still sometimes the text fails... is there something i can do to avoid this inconsistency?

Comment: Oh. You need to do the wrapping before you send the test record. There is a race where you could receive the record before you wrapped the listener.

Comment: i see... yes i was wrapping the listener after sending the message... will do it before and try... thanks for the suggestion...

Comment: @user1945064 is your problem resolved ? Can you post your solution for the benefit of others.

Comment: yes as @Gary Russell recommended i just switched the ordering and do the wrapper on the listener before i produce the message... that solved the issue for me